# Multi Tenancy support for IdentityServer4 with javascript client

Tags: identityserver4

Hi I am using IdentityServer4 with aspnet core application.

I am using MVC client from their sample and also using a javascript client. The javascript client can be opened as tenantone.domain.com or tenanttwo.domain.com and so on according to tenancy name.

I am not able to get authorization for dynamic sub-domains.

Please help! if any one has done such task in asp.net core

To Register the javascript client I am using below code

```
    string tenancyName = "tenantone"

    var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient("http://login.domain.io:5000");
        discoveryClient.Policy.RequireHttps = false;
        var doc = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();

        var request = new IdentityModel.Client.AuthorizeRequest(doc.AuthorizeEndpoint);

        var url = new IdentityModel.Client.AuthorizeRequest(doc.AuthorizeEndpoint).CreateAuthorizeUrl(
         clientId: tenancyName,
         responseType: ResponseTypes.IdTokenToken,
         scope: "openid profile api1",
         redirectUri: "http://" + tenancyName + ".domain.io:5003/callback.html",
         state: "random_state",
         nonce: "random_nonce",
         responseMode: "form_post",
         extra: new
         {
             AllowedCorsOrigins = "http://" + tenancyName + ".domain.io:5003"
         });

        var response = new IdentityModel.Client.AuthorizeResponse(url);

        var accessToken = response.AccessToken;
        var idToken = response.IdentityToken;
        var state = response.State;
```

Then after to be authorized from client I am using below code:

```
    var config = {
        authority: "http://login.domain.io:5000",
        client_id: "tenantone",
        redirect_uri: "http://tenantone.domain.io:5003/callback.html",
        response_type: "id_token token",
        scope: "openid profile api1",
        post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://tenantone.domain.io:5003/",
    };
    var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);

    debugger;

    mgr.getUser().then(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            //log("User logged in", user.profile);
            $("#bodyPage").removeAttr("style");
        }
        else {
           // log("User not logged in");
            mgr.signinRedirect();
        }
    });
```

Comment: you need to clarify and show what you have tried, what is your issue, are you receiving any error message.  From the nothing of code you've given me, my best guess is 1. you didn't configure cors on your client in IdentityServer4,

Comment: are you sure that's adding a client?  What error message do you get when trying to connect?  It might be easier to add an inMemory client first. So you know your registered properly.

Comment: I am getting CORS Issues.

Comment: I'm assuming this is during authentication, Can you post the CORS Policy code you have on the IdentityServer, do you still have your `[SecurityHeader]` Attribute on the controllers,  and did you try configuring this with an inMemory client first?